# Codeigniter URI segment when nothing passed

Tags: php, codeigniter

I working on a Controller and I would like to make sure there is a second URI segment. When I write for example www.example.com/controller/login, it works, returning the second segment which is "login". BUT when I don't pass any second segment, just www.example.com/controller it does not returning anything. I tried to check if it's null or false still the same, does not work. Anyone can help me, please? It seems that if I don't pass a function or method after a controller I won't get anything.

```
        $seg = $this->uri->segment(2, false);
        if($seg != NULL) {
            echo $seg; //this works when I pass login
        }else{
            $first_seg = false; // if I dont pass login, it doesn not working.
        }
```

Comment: please read: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html#CI_URI::segment

Comment: Yeah, I did. I passed false if the segment not found but does not give me back the false.

Comment: Without knowing where in the controller the above code is located any answer is a guess. Please show the function where the code is found.

Comment: if you're missing segment 2 (which is the method being called) nothing should happen. That's the reason you're not getting anything returned on the screen. What you're dealing with is expected codeigniter behavior

Comment: in addition to what javier said, the if else seems redundant as you have specified the 2nd param of the segement function. if the 2nd segement is not present `$seg` will be false. expected behavior of CI, not sure what you wanted in its place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concentrating on your example "debug code" as there's an issue with it and debug code is important to get right.

So, this is more of an *"understand the debug code to debug your code"* answer.

You said you had read the CI userguide on this.

So you have...

```
$seg = $this->uri->segment(2, false);
if($seg != NULL) {
    echo $seg; //this works when I pass login
}else{
    $first_seg = false; // if I dont pass login, it doesn't not working.
}
```

What you have says... If there is no 2nd segment, set $seg to false. If $seg is not NULL, echo $seg. In this case, $seg will never be NULL.

I am disregarding your $first_seg as it's flapping in the breeze and I have no clue what its used for. Where does it ever get set to True etc.

Effectively your code turns into

```
$seg = $this->uri->segment(2, false); // Override the default NULL to false
if($seg != NULL) {
    echo $seg; // This will ALWAYS run as $seg is Never NULL
}
```

Which really boils down to..

```
 $seg = $this->uri->segment(2, false); // Override the default NULL to false
 echo $seg;
```

Interestingly, you cannot display false using echo. It will not display anything on the page (white space). You could use `echo $seg ? $seg: '0';` or something. SO if $seg is true(not false) echo $seg else display 0 to represent false.

You could simply use...

```
$seg = $this->uri->segment(2, 'Nothing'); 
echo $seg;
```

Or better yet

```
$seg = $this->uri->segment(2, 'index'); // No 2nd segment means default index method.
echo $seg;
```

Hope that helps for the future.

AND make sure you read **Javier Larroulet's** answer.

Comment: Thanks your answer, i appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

you're misundertanding the way URI's are mapped in codeigniter.

In Codeigniter:

```
example.com/segment1/segment2/segment3/..../segmentN
```

are mapped this way:
segment1 = controller

segment2 = method

segment3 = parameter 1

segment4 = parameter 2

...

segmentN = parameter N

if segment 2 is missing, you're not specifiying a method, thus nothing will happen.

By default, if no method is specified, CI will attempt to use the `index()` method. So you may want to handle a missing `segment(2)` within the `index` method or in the controller's constructor. Otherwise, you'll not be able to even handle the request.